# Regex pattern to remove square brackets and commas in a json array in order to apply MapReduce

Tags: java, json, mapreduce

Alright, I basically have this a JSON array like this:

```
[
  {
    product:something, 
    version:something
  },
  {
    product: something,
    version: something
  }
]
```

I need to remove the commas in between each json, as in the commas after the curly brackets, I also need to remove the square brackets. This is necessary because I'm deserializing element by element, so if I have a comma or a bracket in between its going to give me an error, or so it would seem to me.

Anyways I've been trying to create a regex pattern to replace those elements. So for example, lets say the first json that is read comes like this as a string:

```
[ 
 {
  product:something,
  version:something
 },
```

So I have my pattern which is this: `[\[\]/}(?=,)]` but then, it matches the last bracket and all of the commas inside the json which is not what I need.

Can someone help me out here? At least refer me to some tutorial or something?

**EDIT:** I can't use any deserializers or any sort of thing like that, basically I'm reading every element of the json array as a line, delimited by "}".

Comment: Why don't you parse the JSON to some workable type (an array, some POJOs, a Map, etc.) then do what you want with the values?

Comment: I would if I could, but the problem is that I have to read it through MapReduce, with '}' delimiting it as a "line".

Comment: You have to read partial JSON? Starting where? Ending where?

Comment: You should really look for an alternate design, changing JSON with regular expressions will turn out to be very fragile.

Comment: I don't know of any, do you have any suggestions? I mean, if I didn't really have to alter it, I wouldn't but that's not really possible.

Comment: Writing JSON parser that works exactly as you need is no hard, if that is a problem - searching for JSON parser that allows streaming instead of parsing whole object may be an alternative. Parsing nested construct with regex is hard, but this is asked multiple times too...

Comment: Can you not just do `jsonArr[0]` and `jsonArr[1]` to get these elements?

Comment: Nope, I cannot, unless MapReduce changed how it works, but then I don't know that much about MapReduce either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this, in which I don't need to involve any regular expressions or alterations towards the JSON. Anyway, here it goes:

First go here https://gist.github.com/Lupus/9988093, get the WholeFileInput format for whichever API it is that you're using. Finally, here's a sample of how I implemented it in one of my mappers:

```
package mapreduce;


import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.json.*;

public class CommonErrorsMapper extends Mapper<NullWritable, BytesWritable, TextTriplet, IntWritable> {


         public void map(NullWritable key, BytesWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            String product;
            String version;
            String errorCode;

            String json = new String(value.getBytes());
            try {
                JSONArray jObject = new JSONArray(json);
                for(int i = 0; i < jObject.length(); i++){
                    product = jObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("product");
                    version = jObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("version");
                    errorCode = jObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("errorCode");
                    context.write(new TextTriplet(product, version, errorCode), new IntWritable(1));
                }
            }catch(Exception error){
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Leaving this here, because I found that mapreduce is incredibly tough to understand, even more so when using a format like JSON. So anyway, that's all there seems to be to it, unless that is someone else found a way to do this without having to read the whole file.